# What's the purpose of the kwargs parameter in the url() function?

Tags: django

The Django's url() function has three parameters:

```
url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None)
```

I'm trying to understand the use of the `kwargs` parameter. Is there any practical example of its functionality?

Comment: See [passing extra options to views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) for an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very useful if you want to pass different arguments to the same function to get different results. In the example below I have a function that serves google analytics templates with a lot of javascript, based on the urls.

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^overall/$', get_analytics_information, kwargs={'template': 'analytics_overall.html'}, name='overall'),
    url(r'^content-terms/$', get_analytics_information, kwargs={'template': 'analytics_content_terms.html'}, name='content_terms'),
    url(r'^campaigns/$', get_analytics_information, kwargs={'template': 'analytics_campaigns.html'}, name='campaigns'),
]

#views
def get_analytics_information(request, template):
    ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = get_access_token()
    if ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT:
        return render(request, '{}'.format(template), {'ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT': ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT})
    else:
        warnings.warn('Invalid service credentials')
        return render(request, 'invalid_credentials.html')
```